# How to iterate through nested ResultPropertyValueCollections in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to AD and Powershell scripting. Here's what I understand. I'm searching AD groups and receive a `ResultPropertyValueCollection`, if the group has members, the `member.count` property is greater than zero. I'd then like to iterate over every member of this group and see if they in turn are also groups, like nested groups, and if so continue recursively.

What I have is this

```
$currentGroup = $Result.Properties.member
while ($currentGroup.Properties.member.count -gt 0) {
    $currentGroup = $currentGroup.Properties.member
}
```

However, after making the assignment on the first line, I cannot call `.Properties.member.count` on `$currentGroup`:

[image]

Looks like it only has `Object` methods.

Weirdly it does however return to be of type `ResultPropertyValueCollection`.

---

UPDATE:

This is what the top-level group looks like:

```
PS C:\Users\CLIENT> $Result.Properties

Name                           Value                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                       
objectclass                    {top, group}                                                                                
usnchanged                     {12814}                                                                                     
whencreated                    {8/15/2019 4:47:50 PM}                                                                      
name                           {Secret_Group}                                                                              
adspath                        {LDAP://gdfgd.corp.com/CN=Secret_Group,OU=CorpGroups,DC=corp,DC=com}                         
  
member                         {CN=Nested_Group,OU=CorpGroups,DC=corp,DC=com} # (*) <-- Nested group is member                                              
samaccounttype                 {268435456}                                                                                 
objectcategory                 {CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=com}                                        
[omitted for brevity]
```

I know that `Nested_Group` again has a group member and I'd like to recursively drill through all groups if that is possible. Please note I'd like to do this using only basic PowerShell functionality.

---

UPDATE 2

Logic for obtaining `$Result`:

```
# 0: Get Domain:
$domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$user = "user
$pw = "pw

# 1: Get Hostname of Primary Domain Controller
$PdcHostName = $domain.PdcRoleOwner.Name

# 2: Assemble distinguished name of domain
$DN = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
$DN = "DC=" + $DN.Replace('.', ',DC=')

# 3: Assemble LDAP provider path
$LDAPPath = "LDAP://" + $PdcHostName + "/" + $DN


# 4: Instantiate Directory Searcher
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]$LDAPPath)

# 4a: Specify search root
$SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($LDAPPath, "$domain.name\$user", $pw)
$Searcher.SearchRoot = $SearchRoot

# 5: Set Filter
$Searcher.Filter = "(&(name=Outer_Most_Group_Name)(objectClass=Group))"

# 6: Perform search
$Result = $Searcher.FindAll()
```

Comment: What PowerShell Cmdlet was used to get $Result?

Comment: Being new to anything is fine, but know that in most cases what you need to get a grip on many things is that there are tools on your system you can use to get educated. For example the Windows Server tool ADAC] ***site:microsoft.com 'ADAC PowerShell History Viewer'***, will write PS code for you that you can tweak as needed.  All you do is use the GUI to do whatever you are wanting, then view the code in the ADAC. You are making this a bit hard on yourself, there are built-in ADDS; if you install/enable RSAT ***site:microsoft.com 'RSAT'*** that provide what you are after by default.

Comment: ADAC isn't robust enough to handle nested groups but I have some PowerShell logic I use for terminated user accounts in AD to get the nested group membership before termination. I'm happy to share that with you but never heard back on the other answer provided on your other question. This post may help, but this is not the logic I use but may help you formulate what you need otherwise: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/aa265e58-00d4-40c0-8a69-a7d6747369ad/how-to-retrieve-group-description-column-when-pulling-nested-groups-using-ldap?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Here's a snippet that may assist if you can confirm with a reply this is what you are after or not (or close enough): https://i.imgur.com/9PlsXPW.png

Comment: @M.Behrens I use a `DirectorySearcher` and provide it an `LDAP` path, on the `Searcher`, I set a `Filter`.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Would be cool to see this PowerShell logic, sounds like something I could use. Sorry if I missed any of your other replies, usually not my style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work

```
$CurrentGroup = $Result
while($CurrentGroup.properties.member.count -gt 0) {
    # Get Common Name
    $nestedGroupName = $CurrentGroup.properties.member.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1]

    $Searcher.Filter = "name=$nestedGroupName"
    $CurrentGroup = $Searcher.FindAll()
    # Do something with $CurrentGroup...
}
```

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Sure, see Update 2, thanks again.